# Variance of jointly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are jointly distributed continuous r.v's with $U \sim Uni(1,3)$ and $V$ given $U = u$ follows an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{u}$. Calculate $Var(V \vert U)$.

Attempt:

Since $U \sim Uni(1,3)$, $f_U(u) = \frac{1}{3-1} = \frac{1}{2} ,\forall u \in (1,3)$. Also $f_{V\vert U}(v \vert u) = ue^{-uv}$ (not sure with this). Then

$$E(V \vert U = u) = \int_{}^{}v f_{V\vert U}(v\vert u)dv$$
$$Var(V\vert U) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (v - E(V \vert U = u))^2f_{V \vert U}(v \vert u) dv$$

Witht that, how do we determine the bounds of integration wrt $v$?

Comment: That looks too complicated.  I would start with $\operatorname{Var}(V \mid U=u)$ which, since this is an exponential distribution $\operatorname{Exp}(u)$, is $\frac1{u^2}$. That makes $\operatorname{Var}(V \mid U) = \frac1{U^2}$

Comment: I edited the question since i copied a wrong phrase

Comment: Changing from rate parameter $u$ to mean parameter $\frac1u$ for the exponential distribution does not affect my comment or tommik's answer

Answer (score 1):

sorry but your question is immediate...and you do not need to know how $U$ is distributed. Are you sure about the question?

You are given that

$$(V|U=u)\sim \text{Exp}(u)$$

thus

$$\mathbb{V}[V|U=u]=\frac{1}{u^2}$$

Sure that you are not asked to find $\mathbb{V}[V]$?

Comment: I edited the question since i copied a wrong phrase

Comment: @860009898987 : there are no significant changes in your question. Knowing that $V|U=u$ is exponential with mean $1/u$ its variance is $1/u^2$.

Comment: I've been solving for more than two hours now my brain must have been exhausted. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the insight!

Comment: also shouldn't it be that $Var(V\vert U) = \frac{1}{u^2}I_{(1,3)}(u)$?

Comment: @860009898987 : yes of course...it was understood